# set uiimage for uiimageview from other viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have faced a problem with setting uiimageview from other viewcontroller.

DiaryDetailController.swift

```
let imageViewPageController = (segue.destinationViewController as! ImageViewPageController)
        if (imageCount > 0) {
            imageViewPageController.image1 = tempImage1
        }
```

ImageViewPageController.swift

```
let page: ImageViewDetailController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("imageViewDetailController") as! ImageViewDetailController
            page.setImage(image1)
            pages.append(page)
```

ImageViewDetailController.swift

```
func setImage(image: UIImage) {
    imageView.image = image
}
```

And I got following error on "imageView.image = image".
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: The code above doesn't show where imageView is declared and instantiated.  If you put a breakpoint on `imageView.image = image` and see if imageView is not nil.  Or if it was declared as an optional originally, then the line should read `imageView?.image = image`

Comment: Do your research before asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu Your IBOutlet is probably disconnected.

Comment: Thank for your comments. I've solved the problem. It was my mistake forgot  linking the IBOutlet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably trying to set the image before the IBOutlets are set.

Create a `UIImage` property in ImageViewDetailController (let's call it `image`), and instead of saying:

```
page.setImage(image1)
```

You can do this

```
page.image = image1
```

Then let the ImageViewDetailController deal with it once it has loaded. So in the `viewDidLoad`, just say

```
imageView.image = self.image
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried your answer but the problem was in linking.